# bash: Use adduser without questions for Full Name, Room Number, etc

Tags: users

I want to use `adduser` in the Bash script, and I want it to only ask for new password, not for Full Name, Room Number, Work Phone, Home Phone, Other, that it asks.

Is there are way to do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Unix.SE. Simply use `--gecos`?! ... you can see existing users with those fields via `getent passwd`. The GECOS fields are separated by `:`. Feel free to take it and run with it (e.g. write a more complete answer).

Comment: Thank you @0xC0000022L! that was what I was searching for.

Comment: Or use `useradd` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @0xC0000022L pointed out in the comments, the solution to my question is to use `--gecos GECOS` option

Example:

```
adduser --gecos GECOS john
```

Then you only get asked to enter user's new password.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. To add user to sudo: usermod -aG sudo john

Comment: @16851556 It's easier to just run `adduser john sudo`.